# If $A$ is a symmetric matrix, then rank($A^{n}$) = rank($A$). Is, this statement true?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

If $A$ is a symmetric matrix over $\mathbb{R}$, then rank($A^{n}$) = rank($A$). Is, this statement true?

For $n=2$ and $n=3$ the statement seems to be true but I have no idea how to prove or disprove for the general case.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you explain us why the statement is true for $n=2,3$?

Comment: Is $n$ an arbitrary (positive) integer? or the dimension of $A$?

Comment: @mr_e_man $n$ is an arbitary positive integer.

Comment: Spectral theorem should do the trick.

Comment: Symmetric matrix over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: @Mathematician42 Symmetric matrix over $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @reego: In that case the spectral theorem answers your question as suggested by nicomezi. The answer below avoids this machinery.

Comment: @Mathematician42 In the case of a symmetric matrix with complex coefficients this becomes wrong: The matrix $\begin{pmatrix}1 & i\\ i & -1\end{pmatrix}$ is symmetric and nilpotent.

Comment: @Claudius : Yes, that's why I specifically asked whether we were working over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $A$ be a symmetric $m \times m$ - Matrix.

If $x \in \ker(A^2)$, then $(Ax|Ax)=(A^2x|x)=0$, hence $x \in \ker(A)$.

This gives $\ker(A)=\ker(A^2)$, hence $\ker(A)=\ker(A^k)$  for all $k \ge 1$.

It follows (why ?): $\mbox{im}(A)=\mbox{im}(A^k)$ for all $k \ge 1$.

Hence $\mbox{rank}(A)=\mbox{rank}(A^k)$ for all $k \ge 1$.

Comment: Good elementary proof. (+1)

Comment: @nicomezi: Thanks !

Comment: What nicomezi said! I was about to invoke the theorem of symmetric matrices being diagonalizable etc :-)

Comment: @Fred What does this mean ? : If $x \in ker(A^2)$, then $(Ax|Ax)=(A^2x|x)=0$.

Comment: $(Ax|Ax)$ is the standard inner product on $\mathbb{R}^N$ of $Ax$ with itself.

Comment: @nicomezi Then how is $(Ax|Ax)=(A^2x|x)$ . Can you please explain ?

Comment: $(Ax|Ax)=(A^TAx|x)$ and $A^T=A$.